# unable to save polygon coordinates in database

Tags: php, postgis

I want to save the JSON coordinates of polygon in the PostGIS database.
This is my PHP code-

```
$coordinates  = ($_POST['Coordinates']);
$query   = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES
   (ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON ('{
                      ['".($coordinates) ."']
      }'), 4326))"
$success =  pg_query($conn,$query);
```

where Coordinates are-

```
{"type":"polygon","coordinates":[[[-97.53662109375,43.67581809328341],[-98.096923828125,42.60970621339408],[-96.427001953125,42.924251753870685],[-97.53662109375,43.67581809328341]]]}
```

but the error is-
***"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$success' (T_VARIABLE)"***
column_name is polygon type column in table.

please someone correct me how to resolve syntax error.
Thanks.

Comment: There might be a semicolon or bracket missing a line before your pasted line.

Comment: You missing `;` after 3-rd line

Answer (score 0):

**T_VARIABLE** error mainly occurs because of the syntax error. You missed a Semicolon before $**success** line. Please check the syntax

```
$coordinates  = ($_POST['Coordinates']);
$query   = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES
   (ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON ('{
                      ['".($coordinates) ."']
      }'), 4326))";
$success =  pg_query($conn,$query);
```

Comment: i have already tried that but then the eror is-
"Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "{" LINE 3: ['{"type":"polygon","coordinates""

Comment: Can you please `echo $query;` and show here

Comment: INSERT INTO polygon (coordinates) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON ('{ ['{"type":"polygon","coordinates":[[[-95.811767578125,41.20345619205131],[-94.46044921875,40.371658891506094],[-95.943603515625,40.34654412118006],[-95.811767578125,41.20345619205131]]]}'] }'), 4326))